# Django - python cut image after checking original Width

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using sorl-thumbnail and PIL for my django site.
How do I cut image when certain conditions meet? For example, create thumbnail of width 600px only when the original image width is greater than 600px.

```
{% thumbnail img.image "600" as im %}
     <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" alt="{{ object.name }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you want the image to simply be 600px or less, i.e. you don't want sorl-thumbnail to stretch it to be 600px always.

If that's the case, you just need to add `upscale=False`:

```
{% thumbnail img.image "600" upscale=False as im %}
     <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" alt="{{ object.name }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```